# Low Power, SD Card module and SCK

Tags: arduino-nano, power, sd-card

in order to minimise power consumption in a project using the Arduino Nano, I need to set pin D13 to HIGH after using it as SCK for transferring data to an SD card module (I use the `SD.h` module. I already read that there are issues, but trying `SdFat.h` somehow made the issue worse). The board is powered by 4*1.3 V batteries, which is within specifications of the chip. The onboard voltage regulator, the power LED and the built-in LED (connected to D13) are torn off the board.

So I power up the module via a MOSFET switch circuit, start the communication with `SD.begin(SDChipSelect)` and write something to the SD card. All of this works just fine. Afterwards, I call `pinMode(SDCLK,OUTPUT); digitalWrite(SDCLK,HIGH);` (where `SDCLK == 13`) before powering off the whole module by closing the MOSFET switch and going to deep sleep forever.

The switch setup (using an n-channel MOSFET) is such that the SD module's VCC is always HIGH, but no current can flow to ground, if the switch is off. Hence I need to turn D13 HIGH, not LOW, in order to turn off the module completely. Changing MISO, MOSI pins didn't affect anything, so I don't change them.

**But**... instead of drawing something like 0.1 mA without anything attached, the Arduino draws around 1 mA, which I can't afford. Apparently, the reason is that D13 doesn't care that I want it to go to HIGH. I can confirm this directly by measuring its voltage as well as by measuring the current drop if I pull off the connection between the SD module's SCK and the D13 pin on the Arduino. If I pull off the wires connecting MISO, MOSI or even the MOSFET itself, power consumption doesn't change.

That being said, power consumption **is** low, if I never write to the card (i.e. if I turn D13 high at in the setup, never power on anything, do **not** initialise the module via `SD.begin(...)`, but go to deep sleep immediately).

What am I doing wrong? Do I somehow need to "end" the communication with the SD module, so I can turn D13 high or is there something special going on with this particular pin?

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
#include <LowPower.h>
#include <SD.h>

static const int GPSPower = 5;
static const int MP3Power = 2;
static const int SDPower  = 8;
static const int SDCLK    = 13;

void blink(int n) {
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
    delay(200);
  }
  return;
}

void setup() {
  // this pin is used in 'blink' to power an LED for debugging
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT); digitalWrite(9,LOW);
  // Set all pins connected to MOSFET gates as low outputs.
  pinMode(MP3Power,OUTPUT); digitalWrite(MP3Power,LOW);
  pinMode(GPSPower,OUTPUT); digitalWrite(GPSPower,LOW);
  pinMode(SDPower,OUTPUT);  digitalWrite(SDPower,LOW);
  // this is D13
  pinMode(SDCLK,OUTPUT); digitalWrite(SDCLK,HIGH);

  // if false, power consumption stays at ~0.1 mA
  // if true, two strings are written and power consumption stays ~1.0 mA
  if (false) {
    String filename = "test.txt";
    write2sd("firststring",filename);
    write2sd("anotherstring",filename);
    blink(3); // feedback for debugging
  }

  // never go into loop
  while (true) {
    LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
  }
}

void loop() {
}

int write2sd(String data, String filename) {
  // power SD module
  digitalWrite(SDPower,HIGH);

  // check availability
  if (!SD.begin(SDChipSelect)) {
    // return early but power off the module first
    pinMode(SDCLK,OUTPUT); digitalWrite(SDCLK,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(SDPower,LOW);
    blink(10); // indicates an error
    return 1;
  }
  // SD Card should be initialised now
  File file = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);

  // write to file 
  if (file) {
    file.println(data);
    file.close();
  }

  // CLK still runs at this point and causes power consumption of ~1mA
  // power it off
  pinMode(SDCLK,OUTPUT); digitalWrite(SDCLK,HIGH); 

  // turn off module power
  digitalWrite(SDPower,LOW);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't change the SPI pins, as long as SPI is enabled. In other words; `digitalWrite(SDCLK,HIGH); 
` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Well I guess that explains it. Is it possible to disable SPI every time after writing?

Comment: Check out this article: https://thecavepearlproject.org/2017/05/21/switching-off-sd-cards-for-low-power-data-logging/

Comment: @Gerben, do you want to write a proper answer, which I can accept? Calling `SPI.end()` at the end of the routine before setting CLK, MISO and MOSI to HIGH afterwards actually works and my power consumption is down to 0.1 mA again :)